# Есть ли аналог str2func из Matlab в C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

Понадобилось портировать проект с Matlab в С++, а там парсится ввод пользователя, который становится вычислимой функцией. Есть ли какой-либо аналог в С++ функции str2func, которая использовалась в Matlab?

Comment: "из коробки" - нет, но есть вагон и тележка различных решений - [парсер выражений](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: @KoVadim, а еще можно вызвать компилятор, сделать .so и дальше dlopen/dlsym

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл [muParser](http://beltoforion.de/article.php?a=muparser) с открытым исходным кодом, распространяющийся по лицензии MIT. Очень неплохо выглядит.

Вот же история жизни: пару дней ищешь что-то, не получается, решаешь распросить народ на сайтах, после этого через минут 15-20 находишь решение. Мда...

Comment: Вот это тоже реальная польза от нашего сайта -)

Comment: BTW, нечто аналогичное (с биндингом переменных и функций) я делал на базе [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) и [PicoC](https://github.com/zsaleeba/picoc). Фактически получается нечто среднее между muParser и вариантом из коммента @avp к вопросу :)